# ThinkPad Edge E540 with `pending-charge` battery state after few months of not using, how to fix that on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: power-management, thinkpad, battery

I turn on my old notebook - Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E540 yesterday and it didn't turn on after few months of being inactive. I thought that maybe battery is discharged to zero and I need power adapter to start. After that, I saw that it works fine on power adapter, but it's constantly not charging up (stack on 6% of battery). After some restarts, battery dropped to 0%... For few moments I saw charging icon in system tray, but after that it changed back to empty red battery icon.

Running `upower` command shows that battery is constantly in `pending-charge` state.

```
user@user-ThinkPad-Edge-E540:~$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               LGC
  model:                LNV-45N1
  serial:               42144
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              pon, 13 lis 2023, 19:00:09 (109 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         37,72 Wh
    energy-full-design:  44 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             8,243 V
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            85,7273%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

Anyone knows how I can fix that? Battery was bought two years ago, worked fine few months ago (like spring). Power charger is original one.

I tried some turn on/off magic from posts I found out here and in google, but without luck. Bios doesn't have otpion to disable power circuit. Keeping laptop on charger for hours didn't change anything...

Thank you for any advices here.

Best,
M.

Comment: check the battery status in BIOS settings menus

Comment: How can I do that @jstola? I don't see any battery status in my BIOS power settings, unfortunately.